# Convert Byte array to an Icon

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a byte array that comes as a result of doing a get to a method called "getFoto()". Now my question is how to convert this array of bytes into an image, to set this image to a specific JLabel.

```
       InputStream myInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(t.getFoto()); 
         BufferedImage someImage;
        try {
            someImage = ImageIO.read(myInputStream);
            Icon icon = new ImageIcon(someImage);
            portada.setIcon(icon);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VeryModificarTrailers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }
```

> `portada.setIcon((Icon) Imagen;` is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A BufferedImage is not an Icon, and so casting will never magically convert it into one. Instead you need to create an ImageIcon first from the image:

```
BufferedImage someImage = ImageIO.read(something);
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(someImage);
someJLabel.setIcon(icon);
```

You can also pass the byte array directly into the ImageIcon constructor as this will work too

Comment: in `BufferedImage someImage = ImageIO.read(something);
Icon icon = new ImageIcon(someImage);
someJLabel.setIcon(icon);` when you put "something" it should be the byte array?

Comment: @Shean98: no, ImageIO requires an InputStream or a File. A ByteInputStream should be adequate.

Comment: I put what you told me and it keeps giving error, I will edit the post so you can see it

Comment: Wait, what error? You've not posted any error message

Comment: Sorry i forgot to put it, its a nullPointerException error in the instruction: `Icon icon = new ImageIcon(someImage);`

Comment: @Shean98 have you tested to see what is null? Before posting this question?

Comment: Your image is likely null, and now you need to debug to find out why.

Comment: Also, that line is not likely the one that throws the NullPointerException. Better check again.